# Cannot use [ ] for reading

Tags: php, syntax, var-dump, superglobals

I tried to do `var_dump($_SERVER[]);`

I received this error:

> Cannot use [] for reading

Any hints for me?

Comment: Because that will create a new numerically-sequenced-key elemenet in the array `$_SERVER`

Comment: A bit more clearance that  all the `super global variables` are itself array types so  no need to add `[]` in front of them

Comment: Thanks guys. All of you are very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

> var_dump($_SERVER);

this will print all the server variables.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, every answer fails to answer the `Why?`.

`$_SERVER[]` is the syntax used to create a new sequential element. The new key will be numertical, starting from 0.

Example:

```
<?PHP
    $array = [];
    $array[] = 1;
    $array['a test'] = 'nope';
    $array[] = 1;

    print_r($array);
```

This will give the following output:

> ```
> Array
> (
>   [0] => 1
>   [a test] => nope
>   [1] => 1
> )
> ```

Why can't you use it for reading?

This is easy: PHP expects you to pass a value to add to the array. Since you don't give any, PHP can't read the element that is trying to create. That is like hatching an egg before there was ever a chicken.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the [] ;) Just use `var_dump($_SERVER);`